# MySQL weird things happening

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql row that I am trying to get distinct number of email addresses grouped by province. And it seems to be giving weird values.

If I do the following (count distinct email addresses for province) for each province

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(email_address)) as COUNT 
FROM entries 
WHERE subscribe='1' 
AND province='ns'
```

and add them all up. I get a number that is roughly 200 more then if I just do

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(email_address)) as COUNT 
FROM entries 
WHERE subscribe='1'
```

which also matches

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(email_address)) as COUNT 
FROM entries 
WHERE subscribe='1' 
AND province IN('ns','nb','pei')
```

but doesn't match

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(email_address)) as COUNT 
FROM entries 
WHERE subscribe='1' 
GROUP BY province
```

if I do

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(email_address)) as COUNT 
FROM entries 
WHERE subscribe='1'
```

So the 2nd one and the 4th one match, and the 1st and 3rd and 5th ones match. But the 2nd/4th is 200 more then the 1st/3rd/5th.

All I want is number of distinct email addresses where subscribe is 1 grouped by province. And it seems to be impossible to get.

Comment: the same email registered in multiple provinces? you can't really compare the various versions together since you're changing the foundation upon which the counts are based. with+without grouping really does alter the conditions drastically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it possible that an email address is tied to more than one province? You can do a query to test this

```
SELECT email_address, count(distinct province)
FROM entries
WHERE subscribe = '1'
GROUP BY email_address HAVING count(distinct province) > 1
```

That may be where your discrepancy is coming in

Either way, this query will give you what you're looking for

```
SELECT province, COUNT(DISTINCT email_address) as COUNT 
FROM entries 
WHERE subscribe = '1' 
GROUP BY province
ORDER BY province
```

Comment: That returns a number that is 200 higher then if I just do a distinct on the email addresses (#5).

Comment: @Steven I updated my answer for another possibility (and moved my original answer to the bottom)

Comment: It does appear that is the problem.